# Problems with null characters in std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, std

I have the following piece of code:

```
static const int   packet_len =10;
std::regex         r_exp;
char c_exp[packet_len +5+ packet_len +1] =
                                 {'\0','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\r','\n',
                                  '(','?','!','.','*',
                                  '\0','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\r','\n',
                                  ')'};
r_exp.assign(c_exp, 26, std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
```

**On some machines, everything works.**

On other machines I get the following error:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std:regex_error'
```

The issue disappears if I test a regex in which `\0` is replaced with a different character.

I cannot understand if I am doing something wrong (so the fact that on some machines it works is just a coincidence), or if there is a real issue with a specific version of the compiler.

I also tried different possibilities, i.e.

```
r_exp=std::string(c_exp,26);
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: Is `26` the same as `packet_len +5+ packet_len +1`?

Comment: To actually match a null char, you need a combination of a literal ``\`` and `0` chars.

Comment: BTW, what is the GCC compiler version on those instances where it fails?

Comment: @al3c yes it is. (I also edited the text).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed that it fails on Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.5.0

Comment: Ok, at any rate, you should not use a null char to match null in std::regex, you need a combination of `'\\'` and `'0'` chars, a literal `\0` text.